# Select a range of results from an SQL result

Tags: sql

I'm looking to grab a selection of entries from an SQL table between 2 given ranges

For example,

```
select * from images_table where catagory = 'trees';
```

gives me 60 results

How to I only get the entries between result 40 and result 60?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, the 40th row is undefined without a column (and `ORDER BY`!) that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to order the results by *something*, because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets -- as do result sets with no `order by`.  Then in Standard SQL you can use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select i.*
from images_table i
where i.catagory = 'trees'
order by i.image_id   -- an example of what you might want to order by 
offset 19 row fetch next 20 rows only;
```

Note that not all databases support `offset`/`fetch` but almost all have similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use **LIMIT**:

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 100, 200
```

However it differs depending on what Database Engine you are using.